# overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Help overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' accepts this number of arguments. after i add another new MySqlDataAdapter then the blue lines showed up

```
Else
    ds = New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO rel_receipt_details values('" & txtornum.Text & "','" & cboparticular.Text & "','" & txtamtpd.Text & "')", conn)
    da.Fill(ds)

    ds = New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO tbl_receipt values('" & txtornum.Text & "','" & CInt(txtstudid.Text.Remove(0, 2)) & "','" & dtpdate.Text & "','" & txtcashier.Text & "')", conn)
    da.Fill(ds)

    ds = New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO tbl_check values ('" & checkno.Text & "','" & CInt(txtstudid.Text.Remove(0, 2)) &  "','" & bankname.Text "','" &  bankbranch.Text & "')",conn)   '<-- Error on this line
    da.Fill(ds)
```

Comment: I have to insert data from 3 tables and at the last one insertion the overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' accepts this number of arguments shown up

Comment: The MySqlDataAdapter is not the correct object to insert directly new records to a datatable.

Comment: IN the commented line you miss a `&` after the `bankname.Text` and the following  `"','"`, but as I have said these lines don't insert anything in the datatable.

Comment: Actually it WILL insert the row, because DataAdapter does not limit the `SelectCommand` and it's OK if you give an `INSERT`. To me it's like towing a car using its antenna: Works but makes no sense.

Comment: @Alireza you are right. I have overlooked the fact that everything you pass as the command text will be blindly passed to the database for execution. So also an INSERT INTO, DELETE, UPDATE and even a CREATE TABLE, if it is syntactically correct, will be executed. I agree on the _makes no sense_.

Answer (score 3):

In the commented line you miss a `&` after the `bankname.Text` and the following `"','"`, but 
if you need to insert directly data in the database table from some input textbox then you should use a MySqlCommand with the appropriate command and ExecuteNonQuery with it.

So, just for example

```
  Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO rel_receipt_details values(@p1,@p2,@p3)"
  Dim cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText,  conn)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtornum.Text)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cboparticular.Text)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtamtpd.Text)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Note that you should not write a command text using string concatenation. Use always a parameterized query to avoid [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and parsing problems caused by strings with embedded quotes or date formats or decimals symbols.

The code above should be repeated for the other two tables. (or you could build a single cmdText with the three commandtexts separated by a semicolon without forgetting the required parameters)

As pointed out by a comment the DataAdapter will insert that data because it will blindly call ExecuteReader on the commandtext passed, but this is completely wrong from a logic point of view. A DataAdapter is used initially to retrieve records from the database and fill a DataSet and then, when you have made changes to the tables (via code or via a binding control like the DataGridView), call the Update method that executes the Insert, Update and Delete required.